# Hide "This iPhone is managed by your organization" message from the lock screen

Tags: iphone, ios

I upgraded my iPhone 6S to iOS 9.3 today and now there appears a message on my lock screen

> This iPhone is managed by your organization.

Of course, I already knew that - it's a company phone!  I don't want to see this message on my lock screen every day, how can I acknowledge the message and disable it?

Comment: You'll see additional messaging in Settings > General > About.  This was added by Apple in iOS 9.3 and even as an MDM admin I can't find a place to disable this messaging.  Until someone gives an alternative answer, I believe Apple controls this rather than the company that manages the phone.

Answer (score 1):

## Removing the management profile

Someone else mentioned how to remove the management profile from the phone. That has some potential issues:

- Your boss may not want you to remove the profile, which may lead to undesired consequences like being fired
- You may lose access to any resources the profile allows you to access
- You may start sending things unprotected directly over the Internet rather than through the VPN your profile sets up for you

## Why the message probably can't be removed

As far as leaving the profile there, it's very likely that you can't remove the message because a lot of people are used to their personal iPhones being secure and private and [they need to be informed when their privacy may be at stake because they may be being watched](http://www.sfgate.com/technology/article/Apple-iOS-9-3-employer-spying-on-employees-6868608.php).

If they're issued a work phone, they may incorrectly assume that the security and privacy are just as good as their own iPhone.

If they let an untrustworthy acquaintance use their personal iPhone, they may have no idea that it's even possible for the acquaintance to take a few minutes to begin managing the phone and to then spy on them later.

Imagine if the boss or the untrustworthy acquaintance could just turn off the warning right after beginning to manage the phone. The user of the phone would then be kept in the dark about potential spying.

There's no easy way for an iPhone to distinguish between a spy disabling the message and the user disabling the message, so there's no easy way to allow for what you want while still ensuring users receive that vital information.

Comment: I see where you're coming from, but there should still be a way to dismiss the message until the status changes again.  It can persist permanently in "settings -> about phone " for example, it doesn't need to stay on the lock screen forever!

Comment: I understand what you mean, but most users very rarely check their settings. This can lead to them being uninformed for a very long time. The lock screen, on the other hand, comes up quite frequently.

Comment: We use JAMF's Casper JSS (MDM) to manage our fleet of iPads. We can put any message we like on the lock screens, and there's nothing the user can do about it. There's no option for the user to modify the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [9-to-5-Mac Blog](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:htPmxmJwYh8J:9to5mac.com/2016/03/02/ios-9-3-makes-it-abundantly-clear-if-your-work-iphone-is-being-tracked-by-your-employer/), the message is simply is alerting you that your iPhone has a profile installed using the **MDM** program.  These are files inside your phone called *.mobileconfig*.  I've linked above to a cached version of this blog, from Google.

These are mostly used to control which preferences and applications you have enabled by default, although there are nearly unlimited advanced uses.  For example your company could easily erase or lock your phone, if desired.  For readers' future reference, you can also create your own profiles or use 3rd party profiles, not just get one from a company.

Depending on the settings of the profile you may be able to remove the profile without your company's consent, although that might not make them happy:

Go into **Settings** and look at the settings for **Profiles**. You can remove the profile from there, if your company is not blocking you from removing profiles.  This may not only make the message go away, but also modify the look and feel of your phone, as well as, remove things you need, like automatic access to company VPNs or wi-fi networks.

There may be a setting within the MDM from your company, that with their admin tools (even just a simple tweak in [Profile Manager](https://www.apple.com/support/osxserver/profilemanager/)) where they can disable this message that you don't like;  I would say just ask about it.  The blog above speculates that this feature has been added because soon there may be more ways implemented for companies to track employees using their managed iphones, in addition to the many already-possible ways to track people using iPhones or other cell phones, such as using GPS.

Comment: To clarify:  I know the phone is managed, and I don't want to remove the profile.  Just don't wish to see the message so prominently displayed on my lock screen, it's not useful information for me.

Comment: The message is part of the upgrade you just did, and now it will always be there when you have a profile present.  James mentioned this in the comment above, and I mentioned it in the answer.

Comment: You only have two options for sure, remove the profile, or wait for someone at your company to tweak their profile so that it does not show the message-- and according to the comment earlier from @james_fuller this is either not possible, or certainly not in the front-end mdm-admin settings.